# Python filter tuples with different sizes

Tags: python-2.7, filter

I'm trying to filter this list of tuples:

```
listTuples = [(50,), (60,), (70,), (120,), (50, 50), (60, 50), (70, 50), (120, 50), (50, 50,60), (60, 50, 60), (70, 50, 60), (120, 50, 60), (50, 50, 60, 70), (60, 50, 60,70), (70, 50, 60, 70), (120, 50, 60, 70)]
```

the filter will check if the **sum of the tuple is bigger then 100**

How Can I do that in python using `filter` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#lambda) function with the build-in [sum](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sum)

```
>>> listTuples = [(50,), (60,), (70,), (120,), (50, 50), (60, 50), (70, 50), (120, 50), (50, 50,60), (60, 50, 60), (70, 50, 60), (120, 50, 60), (50, 50, 60, 70), (60, 50, 60,70), (70, 50, 60, 70), (120, 50, 60, 70)]
>>> filter(lambda x:sum(x)>100,listTuples)
[(120,), (60, 50), (70, 50), (120, 50), (50, 50, 60), (60, 50, 60), (70, 50, 60), (120, 50, 60), (50, 50, 60, 70), (60, 50, 60, 70), (70, 50, 60, 70), (120, 50, 60, 70)]
>>>
```